# Javascript, make a variable inside a function globally available

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables, p5.js

this application has 2 select functions, the first select function takes data from a json file. when one is selected it saves the ID in a variable. this variable is created using let outside the function. in the second select function it takes data from a json file and only shows the data where the ID from the json matches the ID saved in the first select variable.

The problem is that the variable cant be found outside of the function. when i console the variable outside the function it came back undefined

I tried changing the variable from let to var. this didn't work. i expected it to be solved but instead there didn't happen anything diffrent.

`````
let locID;
let select;
let select2;

function preload() {
  data = loadJSON(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mia-mmt2-2223/leesfestival/main/festival.json"
  );
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //LOCATION  SELECTION
  //create select element with as options name from locations from json
  select = createSelect();
  select.position(10, 10);
  select.option("Select a location");
  for (let i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {
    select.option(data.locations[i].name);
  }
  //when a location is selected, save the location id
  select.changed(function () {
    item = select.value();
    for (let i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {
      if (data.locations[i].name == item) {
        locID = data.locations[i].id;
      }
    }
  });

  //WORKSHOP SELECTION
  //create select element with as options name from workshops where location matches locID from json
  select2 = createSelect();
  select2.position(10, 50);
  select2.option("Select a workshop");
  for (let i = 0; i < data.workshops.length; i++) {
    if (data.workshops[i].location == locID) {
      select2.option(data.workshops[i].name);
    }
  }
}````
`````

Comment: Did you try to console log just after the value is assigned ? After locID = data.locations[i].id; ? Is value being assigned

Comment: the json link is broken